# How can I force a button to do some action automatically?

Tags: javascript

**Problem**

I have a form with different stages. **Image below** in which I have multiple buttons(prev, next) and a submit button(to submit the form). I want to take the person directly to 5th stage (summary) with pre-populated data when they comes to this page.

I am using below mentioned **javascript code** but no success. I know the reason why no success and that is because in javascript I'm doing action on **submit button** whereas I want to do it on a normal button, which looks like this.

Can anybody guide my through the syntax of JavaScript in terms of how should I make an action only on the below mentioned button.

**Button**

```
<button type="button" class="next" onclick="loadnext(4,5);"><img src="images/next.jpg" alt="" /> </button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   document.forms.login_form.submit();
</script>
```

**Loadnext function**

```
function loadnext(divout,divin){
   console.log(divout + " -- " + divin);
   ch=validateme_form(divout,divin);
   if(!ch){return false}

   //alert(ch);

   jQuery("." + divout).hide();
   jQuery("." + divin).fadeIn("fast");
}
```

Comment: Paste the code of loadnest func please. The Javascript you show is executed at the moment the document load reaches it. So, it is not submiting the form.

Comment: @mtsiakiris Please find the loadnext func code above. I have edited my ques. thnks

Answer (score 0):

`document.forms.login_form.submit();` does not trigger the click event of your button, trigger it directly (sth. like `jQuery("button.next").click()`), but be sure to wait, that the dom is ready. (`jQuery(function() { ... }`)

Answer (score 0):

OK, you have a form and you collect values from showing and hiding some divs and you want to post the form at the end as I can see.

1. Place the loadnext function inside a  in  section.
2. Since the button is not submit leave it as it is, or if you like it to serve as submit also change the onclick to onclick="loadnext(4,5); return false;"
3. I do't know what validateme_form does, but I think it will work.
4. make sure all elements have the correct ids as needed.

Hope this helps.